# Resizing a Listbox in Python Tk app

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter
import ttk
import datetime

from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Entry, Button, Listbox, N, S, E, W

class TkPersonalActivityLog(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def configure_window(self, root):

        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=2)

        self.frame = Frame(root)
        self.frame.grid(sticky=N+E+S+W)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=2)
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=2)

        self.entry = Entry(self.frame, bg='#e3ecfc')
        self.entry.grid(row=0, sticky=E+W)
        self.entry.focus_set()

        self.savebutton = Button(self.frame, text="Save and Minimize", fg="Black", command=self.cb_save_button)
        self.savebutton.grid(row=1)

        self.history = Listbox(self.frame)
        self.history.grid(row=2,sticky=N+S+E+W)

    def cb_save_button(self):
        act = (datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), self.entry.get())
        self.history.insert(0, ' '.join(act))

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.configure_window(self.root)
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = TkPersonalActivityLog()
    main.mainloop()
```

I want `self.history` to resize to the bottom of the window on resizing the entire window. As it is, it's not doing that:

[image]

That is, it does resize horizontally to the sides of the main window as I want it, but it does not resize vertically to the *bottom* of the window.

Why is that? After all, I do tell it to be `sticky=N+S+E+W`?

Comment: I think if you give the root window and `self.frame` distinctive background colors, you might be surprised at what you see. Doing so will help validate whether your assumption that `self.frame` fills the whole window is true or not. That will then tell you whether the problem is with the listbox or if it's with something else.

Comment: @BryanOakley By the way, could you please explain why the widgets are packed into the window, while (as far as I understand) they are packed into the frame, and the frame is never packed?

Comment: @Rightleg The frame is place in the root window with `grid()`

Comment: @SierraMountainTech Oh my bad, I skipped the line because they all start with `grid_`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save your self some headache if you just import Tkinter as tk.

Try changing this:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Entry, Button, Listbox, N, S, E, W
```

To:

```
Import Tkinter as Tk
```

Also you do not need to import `N, S, E, W` as you can use a string for those direction. So `sticky = "nsew"` works just as well as `sticky = N+S+E+W`
Your main issue is not the listbox not filling the frame but rather your `self.frame` not filling the root window.

First lets remove all the useless weights. Because your `self.frame` is only being placed on `row=0, column=0` and you have no other widgets placed in the root window there is no need to provide weights to other rows/columns.

Change this:

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=2)
```

To:

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Then lets change the weights of the Frame so that the list box expands.

Change:

```
self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=2)
self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=2)
```

To:

```
self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
```

This should fix your resizing problem.

Results:

[image]

On a different note you are importing methods from tkinter more than once. This should be avoided and is not needed. Here is a modified version of your code that I think is a bit cleaner and requires less lines to complete the same task.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter as tk
import datetime

class TkPersonalActivityLog(object):

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.master = root
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.grid(sticky="nsew")
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.frame, bg='#e3ecfc')
        self.entry.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
        self.entry.focus_set()

        self.savebutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Save and Minimize", fg="Black", command=self.cb_save_button)
        self.savebutton.grid(row=1)

        self.history = tk.Listbox(self.frame)
        self.history.grid(row=2,sticky="nsew")

    def cb_save_button(self):
        act = (datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), self.entry.get())
        self.history.insert(0, ' '.join(act))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = TkPersonalActivityLog(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This code is shorter and prevents multiple imports by using `import Tkinter as Tk`.